# How to query for all the attributes in xtdb

Tags: clojure, xtdb

the following code works, and it retrieves a set of all post ids and their titles -

```
(xt/q db '{:find [post title]
                       :where [[post :post? true]
                               [post :header title]]})
```

however, I forgot what were the other attributes of these post objects inside my database. and I want to find out what they were. how can I find them?

is there a way to do something equivalent to? -

```
select *
from some_table
where post = true
```

also what is the best way to inspect and manually edit xtdb databases?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used XTDB myself, but try this:

```clj
(xt/q db '{:find  [(pull post *)]
           :where [[post :post? true]]})
```